# Javascript - How can I make this regex code global?

Tags: javascript, regex

I think I am missing one line somewhere, or need to change one line. I tried various /g methods but I think the exec is killing me here, maybe I am missing some small easy addition, or maybe the way I have written it is flawed. Saw a lot of threads where one mentioned while looping the exec but that seemed to infinite loop because I am including the match in the replacement.

Here is the code I got so far

```
var system_url="http://somesite.com/";
$('.words').mouseover(function(){
  var re=new RegExp("[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9]{5}");
  var m=re.exec($(this).html());
  if (m == null) {
    re=new RegExp("[0-9]{5}");
    m=re.exec($(this).html());
    if (m == null) {}else{
      if ($(this).html().match("</a>")) {}else{
        tx=$(this).html().replace(m,"<a href='"+system_url+m+"' target='_blank' title='Ticket: "+m+"'>"+m+"</a>");
        $(this).html(tx);
      }
    }
  }else{
    if ($(this).html().match("</a>")) {}else{
      tx=$(this).html().replace(m,"<a href='"+system_url+m+"' target='_blank' title='Ticket: "+m+"'>"+m+"</a>");
      $(this).html(tx);
    }
  }
});
```

Some HTML Class:

```
<span class='words'>The quick brown ZAD-14034 jumped over the EAD-14534</span>
<span class='words'>The 13034 brown fox jumped over the ZEN-12274</span>
```

Comment: Instead of doing `if (cond) {} else { ... }` you can do `if (!(cond)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a regex literal as `/expr/flags`. The `RegExp` constructor is used as `new RegExp("expr", "flags")`. Thus, in your case the usage would be:

```
new RegExp("[0-9]{5}", "g");
```

At the same time, you gain no advantage of using the constructor over a literal, so try using this syntax:

```
re = /[0-9]{5}/g;
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

**UPDATE:**

An attempt to fix your code:

```
var system_url = "http://somesite.com/";

$(".words").on("mouseover", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass("replaced")) {
        var currentContent = $this.text();
        var re = /([A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{5})/g;
        var newContent = currentContent.replace(re, "<a href='" + system_url + "$1' target='_blank' title='Ticket $1'>$1</a>");
        $this.html(newContent);
        $this.addClass("replaced");
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5bJ5N/1/

Comment: Or just use a regex literal, since there's nothing gained by using the constructor here: `/[0-9]{5}/g`

Comment: What is a better way to to exec so it actually does no global?

Comment: @MattBall Haha very true, don't know why I didn't think of suggesting that

Comment: The default is non-global. Adding the global flag makes it global. If I'm not mistaken, you can re-use the regex to control the global-ness. Iterate yourself instead of automatically via a flag.

Comment: This is cool but it does not go global in my code, i think because of exec, any other way I can use something other than exec based on my code?

Comment: @user2328185 It **seems** to work for me - http://jsfiddle.net/5bJ5N/, although I see that it isn't replacing all instances. That's because the first parameter for `replace` needs to be a regex, not a result of `.exec`

Comment: @user2328185 I'm very unclear as to what you're trying to do. If you want `re` to be global, define it outside mouseover or use `window.re`. The `window` DOM object is basically the global context. Anything defined as `window.varname` will be globally accessible. That being said, global variables are not great programming practice.

Comment: What I am trying to do here is parse dynamically added elements to a page which have the same class. Parsing one instance of what I am searching for I am able to accomplish, it is parsing other possible matches in the given string I am having an issue with. Since Exec only grabs the first result, posting an answer that I should use /somereg/g cannot be a valid reply. I'm sorry guys.  Is there an alternative I should be using to exec in order be able to use /g properly? Once I get that working I can worry about moving var outside the function.

Comment: @user2328185 Using the "g" flag is the correct answer. Applying it like I suggested isn't. You don't need to use `exec`. Just use `replace` and pass it a regex. What you pass to `replace` is just a string, which only replaces the first occurrence. Let me try and fix the example. The problem is your logic, not your regex

Comment: @user2328185 I updated my answer to include how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks for trying, while this does do a global find it changes the class of the elements which would not work in my scenario, also it does not find elements like "12345" only "ABC-12345". I did not need an optimized code as I can optimize it all I want once I get it working. It would need to find ABC-12345 first then try to find 12345 after. I'll figure it out, as my original post stated I thought maybe I was missing one /g somewhere or something, if not  Looks like I need to try another method. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user2328185 You never explained what you actually wanted your code to do. Your code wasn't correctly working, so how can I know what you want to happen? Like I said, the important thing is that the `.replace()` needs a regular expression as the first parameter (with the "g" flag) in order to replace things globally. You don't need to use `.exec()` at all or nearly as much as you did.